# $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is /index.html when requesting any path with PHP built-in server and Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, php-builtin-server

I have this weird behaviour where if the path does not contain a period (/whatever-something/a-page for example), the `$_SERVER` variable `SCRIPT_NAME` is replaced with index.html or index.php if they exist in the root folder. `SCRIPT_NAME` is the correct value: /whatever.something/a-page when there is no index.html or index.php in the root folder.

I check the SCRIPT_NAME value in the router_dev.php that Symfony provides.

I run the server like this: `app/console server:run`

Example 1 - GOOD

```
Directory structure:
web/index.html

Path:
/whatever.something/a-page

SCRIPT_NAME value:
/whatever.something/a-page
```

Example 2 - GOOD

```
Directory structure (empty):
web/

Path:
/whatever-something/a-page

SCRIPT_NAME value:
/whatever-something/a-page
```

Example 3 - WEIRD!

```
Directory structure:
web/index.html

Path:
/whatever-something/a-page

SCRIPT_NAME value:
/index.html
```

This causes my app to serve the index.html on basically every request that doesn't contain a period.

Can someone tell me what the hell is going on?

Comment: @sємsєм I don't like your title edits, it's not better and it's actually wrong. Please revert.

Comment: As you like and Sorry.